# View online Email and Ampscript to update CRM not working properly

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email

We have an email containing a content block that should retrieve a coupon number from a Data Extension, based on this coupon number assign the coupon record (from coupon object) to the account in CRM.
The journey can assign multiple coupons every 3 months to the same contact.
To avoid the coupon being assigned more than once we use message context to stop this from happening when previewing online.

However, when previewing online, a few days after the email has been sent the wrong data and wrong coupon number (if more than one is assigned) is displayed.

Is there a way to have the view online display a screenprint of the email at the moment of send instead of making it call again the server?

Comment: It will be helpful, if you could share the Ampscript being in charge of assigning and displaying the coupon. Otherwise we have little insights needed to help you.

Comment: @LukasLunow the question is at the bottom, is there a way to not make the ampscript recall the server when the view as web page is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VAWP will continue to execute AMPscript as long as the connection to the sending data extension row exists -- which is what the `qs` parameter on the URL enables.

I'd suggest adding an additional AMPscript conditional when `_messageContext == "VAWP"` to display alternate content after a certain period of time after the send.  How you arrive at that period and what date you use to determine the delta is where I'd start.

You could add your coupon code to the sendlog at send time and retrieve it instead.  That's not a retroactive solution, but it's a good, built-in way to store static values from the send.

Comment: Adam that is what we did in the end, we are claiming a row in a CouponDataExtension, that contains the coupon number we are assigning and add the JobId and BatchId + Contactkey and coupon definition ID then we call these variables in the VAWP to conditionally show the coupon that was sent during the batch id and job id. 
As batch id is unique to job id.